# How to build a module with dependencies in an AAR file

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea, aar

## Part 1

I want to build an AAR of an Android module that have some dependencies.

Let's call my module `MyModule` and `App` the application that is using it. I want to import `MyModule` on `App`. So I do:

```
implementation 'com.example.mymodule:mymodule@aar'
```

To launch `App` I must import `MyModule` and its dependencies. For example, if `MyModule` depends on AndroidVolley, in `App` I must import `MyModule` and AndroidVolley.

Why Gradle of `App` doesn't understand that `MyModule` has a dependency on AndroidVolley and it is not automatically imported?

## Part 2

I don't want obfuscate the code since I want that developers using `MyModule` can read the documentation of each method and the name of the parameters.

The way I do it now, when you use my generated AAR you are only able to see the decompiled code wich is missing some parameter names and the classes don't have documentation.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Please send the part that you imported volley in your Mymodule

Comment: Why do you need that? I have volley as a dependency of MyModule. I just need it to make MyModule works.